# Improving clarity of embedded videos using media9

Tags: media9, embedding

I am using the media9 package to embed an mp4 file in my PDF. However, the embedded video is a bit blurry and makes the animation difficult to see. The video's frame is 672x504 (4:3). What are some ways to improve that?

```
\includemedia[
  width=0.672\linewidth,
  height=0.504\linewidth,
  keepaspectratio,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=myvideo.mp4,
  flashvars={
    source=myvideo.mp4
    &scaleMode=letterbox
  }
]{}{VPlayer9.swf}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options for playing a video at its original size without resampling:

(1) embedded in the page: append FlashVar `scaleMode=none`; the video widget must be large enough to see everything:

```
\includemedia[
  width=0.672\linewidth,
  height=0.504\linewidth,
  activate=pageopen,
  addresource=myvideo.mp4,
  flashvars={
     source=myvideo.mp4
    &scaleMode=none
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

(2) playback in a floating window:

```
\includemedia[
  windowed=672x504,
  addresource=myvideo.mp4,
  flashvars={
     source=myvideo.mp4
%    &scaleMode=none  % not necessary here
  }
]{\fbox{Click!}}{VPlayer.swf}
```

Comment: The floating window option works better but I feel it might have something to do with my screen's resolution. Thank you!